# What order does Bitcoin Core place the inputs it spends in?

Tags: bitcoin-core, coin-selection, transaction-input

What order does Bitcoin core place the inputs it spends in? Is it random? Is it sorted by anything? What, if anything, can you tell about the originator of a transaction by the input ordering?

Comment: related: [What is the coin selection algorithm?](http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/1077/5406)

Answer (score 5):

The inputs are chosen by the function `SelectCoins()` in [`CreateTransaction()`](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/blob/0.11/src/wallet/wallet.cpp#L1801) and then [added one by one (without shuffling)](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/blob/0.11/src/wallet/wallet.cpp#L1899) to the transaction.

The order is defined by the coin selection (`CWallet::SelectCoinsMinConf`) which does a random shuffle of the potential useful inputs and a stochastic approximation.

Mind also that Bitcoin-Core's coin selection could be improved and there are several issues and improve proposals ([[1]](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/pull/4906), [[2]](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/issues/1643), [[3]](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/issues/3631))